# How to set "less" and "lesspipe" correctly?

Tags: zsh, vim, less

I had set less to a vim less functionality some years ago and I would like to reverse those changes. Therefore I started removing the alias from "~/.zshrc". Since after sourcing this file my system told me that when I type "less" I wanted to access the vim less functionality I added those two exports:

```
export LESSOPEN="|lesspipe.sh %s"
export LESS="/usr/bin/less"
```

and the following alias

```
alias less="/usr/bin/less"
```

"ls -l \less" did not present me the target of the default target of less so I couldn't see what the actual default symbolic link of less targeted

After sourcing the file everything works fine except for the fact that I will now receive the line "There is no -/ option ("less --help" for help)".

How can I fix this problem, why does it even appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `less` man page:

> **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**
>
> `LESS`:   Options which are passed to `less` automatically.

The point of the environment variable is to configure default options for `less`. You could do:

```
export LESS=FRX
```

for instance for the `-F`, `-R` and `-X` options to be passed automatically.

So you don't want to put a path to a `less` executable in there. Doing so would tell `less` to try and interpret it as options. `/` is not a valid option name for `less`.

Also, the `alias less=/usr/bin/less` should only be necessary if there are more than one `less` versions installed on the system and it's the one in `/usr/bin` you want as opposed to the one that would be found via a `$PATH` lookup.

Even then, using an alias is not necessary there, you could use `hash less=/usr/bin/less` instead to tell the shell the preferred path to the `less` command.